# awk - Duplicate, Rearrange and Add columns to file

Tags: awk

I would like to :

1. duplicate 2 columns
2. switch position between columns
3. add a variable (as: 0,128,128) in a column at the end of the file

My file :

```
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +
....continue
```

My code :

```
cat FILE.txt | awk 'BEGIN { FS=" "; OFS="\t" } { print $1, $2=$2 "\t" $2, $3=$3 "\t" $3, $4, $5, $6 }' | awk 'BEGIN { FS="\t"; OFS="\t" } { print $1, $2, $4, $6, $7, $8, $3, $5 "\t" "0,128,128" }' > FILE.bed
```

My out-put :

```
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +
        3006607 3006623 0,128,128
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +
        3006607 3006623 0,128,128
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +
        3006607 3006623 0,128,128
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +
        3006607 3006623 0,128,128
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +
        3006607 3006623 0,128,128
...continue
```

**ERROR = DUPLICATED COLUMNS AND THE ADDED ONE ARE IN A ROW BELOW**

What I would like to obtain !

```
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +  3006607  3006623   0,128,128
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +  3006607  3006623   0,128,128
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +  3006607  3006623   0,128,128
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +  3006607  3006623   0,128,128
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +  3006607  3006623   0,128,128
.....continue
```

What am I doing wrong?
Am I missing NR or paste0?

Comment: It's not at all obvious how you came up with such a complicated script. Is there more to the problem you're trying to solve that you haven't told us about yet? Regarding `Am I missing NR or paste0` - what do you think either of those might have to do with your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code in your question produces output that puts the duplicated values on a new row then your input has DOS line endings (or similar?) causing that to happen because your code **will not** do that.

See [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for how to handle DOS line endings and then this is all you really need instead of the script in your question:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $0, $2, $3, "0,128,128"}' file
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +   3006607 3006623 0,128,128
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +   3006607 3006623 0,128,128
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +   3006607 3006623 0,128,128
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +   3006607 3006623 0,128,128
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +   3006607 3006623 0,128,128
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```sh
awk -v OFS='\t' -v s='0,128,128' '{$1=$1; print $0, $2, $3, s}' file

chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +   3006607 3006623 0,128,128
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +   3006607 3006623 0,128,128
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +   3006607 3006623 0,128,128
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +   3006607 3006623 0,128,128
chr1    3006607 3006623 Class   0   +   3006607 3006623 0,128,128
```

`$1=$1` is to force `$0` to be reformatted with tab as field separator.